# Android: Adding Frames to images

Tags: java, android, image, canvas, image-editing

I have two images. One is a simple image and the second is a fancy frame. I want to set the frame on the image. I searched through some blogs, but unable to find an answer.
Could anyone tell me the idea or any concept about how to do that?

Comment: Hi,Your requirement is image filters like snap,b612 ??

Comment: The question is a bit vague and not specific. Can you explain the problem in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can you `FrameLayout` to use 2 Images 1 over other like below to achieve like Frame -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image2"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, true. But I want to drag image1 to fit on the frame(image2). How to do this?